# jQuery working in everything but IE7. (checked my commas)

Tags: jquery, validation, uploadify

The following code works in IE8, FF, Safari, Chrome etc. (not bothering with IE6 for this one), but doesn't work in IE7. I've been through the code with a fine tooth-comb. Checked the commas, messed around with `;` but it's not going anywhere. I'm using the jQuery Validate and Uploadify scripts.

Can anyone see the problem here? Thanks.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $("#validateform").validate({
                errorClass: 'invalid',
                rules: {
                    bike_url: {
                        required: true,
                        url: true
                    }
                }   
            })

            $("#uploadify").uploadify({
                'uploader'  : '<?php echo $url . '/wp-content/plugins/biketest/includes/uploadify/uploadify.swf'; ?>',
                'script'    : '<?php echo $url . '/wp-content/plugins/biketest/class/class.uploadify.php'; ?>',
                'folder'    : '<?php echo $url . '/wp-content/plugins/biketest/uploads'; ?>',
                'cancelImg' : '<?php echo $url . '/wp-content/plugins/biketest/includes/uploadify/cancel.png'; ?>',
                'auto'      : true,
                'fileDesc'  : '.jpg or .png files only please.',
                'fileExt'   : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;',
                'sizeLimit' : '2097152',
                'buttonText': 'Choose Image',
                'scriptData': { 
                    'random': '<?php $rand = rand(0, 999999); echo $rand ?>'
                },
                'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                    var image = '<?php echo $rand; ?>-' + ((fileObj.name).toLowerCase()).replace(' ', '');

                    setTimeout(function(){ $(".uploaded").attr('src', '<?php echo $url; ?>/wp-content/plugins/biketest/uploads/s-' + image); }, 500);
                    $("[name=bike_img]").val(image);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Any error messages, exceptions in IE?

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: What's the error message you're getting from IE7?

Comment: I only have ieTester, which just crashed and on reopen it all works. I'd been doing a 'no cache' refresh, so I don't know what happened.
I don't believe it! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some more '...

like this:

```
$("#validateform").validate({
                'errorClass': 'invalid',
                'rules': {
                    'bike_url': {
                        'required': 'true',
                       'url': 'true'
                    }
                }   
            })
```

basically every such key/value should be bewteen ''.

Comment: I added the `'` to the keys, but any value that is `true` or `false` shouldn't have `'` around it.

Comment: Well, i've always added them everywhere for IE and it makes it work with IE7 & IE6. Example:
$('#sliderwrap').serialScroll({
    'items':'div.sliderretsept',
    'prev':'#prev',
    'next':'#next',
    'navigation':'.pagin ul li a',
    'start':0,
    'duration':500,
    'interval':7500,
    'force':'true',
    'stop':'false',
    'lock':'false',
    'cycle':'true'
   }); I only leave numerical values out of ''